# UNET library server compatibility

Tags: c#, node.js, networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

firstly I have to say that I'm new to Unity3d, so please be kind to me :).
I'm about to start a project with Unity3d and I read from Unity docs that for the networking part of the game can be used a class provided by the Unity staff called UNET, i saw some examples but I can't understand what I have to implement server-side. Do I have to use a specific library made by Unity for C# also on the server? Because I planned to use node.js..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want and what you need.
Actually there is no built-in server, but everything you need to make your own.

Your server can be in the same build or a separated one, no problem.
You can use nodejs, or everything you want. It will probably be more performant, but harder because you'll have more work at low level and less ressources to help you.

But I know some people did it.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tutorial-sample-game-multiplayer-nodejssocketio-wach-livis-rafael